# Ruby on Rails - Cannot assign local variable for haml partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partial-views

```
- content_for :logo, render('logo', :obj => @sites_page)
```

`raise` in _logo.html.haml

```
-raise local_variables.inspect
= link_to popup_information_path(obj.class.short_name, obj), :remote => true do
    - image_tag(obj.user.avatar.url)
```

shows that local variable obj does exist

```
[:local_assigns, :output_buffer, :_old_virtual_path, :_old_output_buffer,
:logo, :obj, :_hamlout, :_erbout, :__in_erb_template, :name, :url,  
:path, :haml_temp]
```

but without `raise` it complaints:

```
undefined local variable or method `obj' for #<#<Class:0xadcdb88>:0x9cc9fd0>

Extracted source (around line #1):

1: = link_to popup_information_path(obj.class.short_name, obj), :remote => true do
2:     - image_tag(obj.user.avatar.url)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out `- content_for :logo, render(:partial => 'logo', :locals => {:obj => @sites_page})`

Comment: what if you render partial without `content_for`? I dont see any mistake in partial rendering

Comment: yep, finally I got rid of partial. Thanks, Sergey.